# Is possible to use a QUERY() inside of SWITCH()?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am doing a spreadsheet in Google Sheets and one of my formulas is full of “if”, so I tried to use a switch instead. The problem is, I need the output to be a query but I only get the first cell of my query. I don’t know if it’s because I can’t use a query in switch or if I am making a syntax mistake. I would really appreciate the help.

```
=switch(A1, “car”, query(‘Other Sheet’!B1:B, “select * where B > 10”))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's possible but only if all 3 ranges are of equal size. example:

```
=SWITCH(A1:B2, {"j","k";"l","o"}, {11,12;13,14})
```

[image: 0]

---

in your cases its better to use nested `IF`

```
=IF(A1="car", QUERY('Other Sheet'!B1:B, "where B > 10"),
 IF(A1="bus", QUERY('Other Sheet'!B1:B, "where B > 500"), )
```

Comment: Switch statement : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en